# Count Linked List Nodes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the numbers of nodes in a linked list when the node value is a non-negative odd, but it seems that I couldn't get the right result.

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param head: 
    @return: nothing
    """
    def countNodesII(self, head):
        count = 0
        while head.next is not None:
            head = head.next
            if head.val > 0 and head.val % 2 != 0:
                count += 1 
            else:
                return 0
        return count
```

if the input is 1->3->5->null
I expect to get result of 3, but my program returned 2 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues in your code

- You would want to move to next node via `head=head.next` after you check the head node for the condition, right now you are skipping `head`
- You would want to remove `return` from else, and only return `count` at the end
- You want to check if head reaches None since you are using it to iterate over your list

So the updated code will look like

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param head: 
    @return: nothing
    """
    def countNodesII(self, head):
        count = 0
        #Iterate over the list
        while head != None:
            #Check for condition
            if head.val > 0 and head.val % 2 != 0:
                count += 1
            #Move to next node
            head = head.next
        return count
```

Comment: Exactly this :D

Comment: That this is the exact and simplest solution ;)

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful!